# Baking High Poly to Low Poly Problem

Tags: baking, retopology

I am trying to bake my high poly model on to a low poly mesh, but I just can't get it to work. I have looked up many tutorials and have tried many different methods, but all I get is this purple texture, not sure why.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated and here is a link to the file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EUdzmTz7eZjoVCong4saU6ImBiBBCvmB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The file link doesn't work. It's private. You need to set the permissions to 'public' for the file.

Comment: Have you tried to do it without an addon?  Is it possible this is a problem with the addon, where one of us should edit the question to reflect that?

Comment: Alright, turns out I messed up my UV unwrap and that was causing the issue, thanks for commenting everybody.